# differntial geometry

Tags: geometry

i m facing much difficulty in understanding behaviour of acceleration vector relating to unit normal vector &unit tangent vector .

However,study reveals that tangent vector is perpendiular to accelerating vector.

Also all three (unit tangent vector ,unit normal vector & accelerating vector) lie in a plane.

My prob is that if all lie in a plane ...then how it is possible for them to be ortogonal in above said way?

Comment: This site is for question about the software program called *Mathematica* (see http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).  This seems to be a question about mathematics.  Is that right?

Answer (score 0):

There's a lot of missing context in the question, but it may help to give names to various quantities. Let's say $I$ is a non-empty interval of real numbers and you have a smooth regular curve $\mathbf{x}:I \to \mathbf{R}^{n}$, i.e., a twice continuously-differentiable map with non-vanishing velocity. For simplicity, assume $T'$ is non-vanishing.

Let $T$ and $N$ denote the unit tangent field and the unit normal field:
$$
T(t) = \frac{\mathbf{x}'(t)}{\|\mathbf{x}'(t)\|},\qquad
N(t) = \frac{T'(t)}{\|T'(t)\|}.
$$
You're perfectly correct that $T$ and $N$ are mutually-orthogonal unit vectors, and that the acceleration $\mathbf{x}''(t)$ lies in the plane spanned by $T(t)$ and $N(t)$.

Moreover, if the curve has unit speed, i.e., is parametrized by arc length, then you're also correct that the acceleration $\mathbf{x}''(t)$ is orthogonal to $T(t)$.

The misunderstanding seems to be the belief that the acceleration is also orthogonal to $N(t)$; in fact, under the preceding conditions, $\mathbf{x}''(t)$ is *parallel* to $N(t)$; the constant of proportionality is the *curvature* $\kappa(t)$.